# Dynamically putting the from action value in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to put form action dynamically In IInd from which value is coming from a drop down of Ist form which is actually a permalink.

the Ist form which have dropdown option is:

```
 <form action="" method="post" name="selectcat">            
            <label>Select your List <span>*</span></label> 
          <select name="contri_id" id="page_id" >                
              <option value="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">           
           </select>        
      </form>
```

the IInd form where I want to put the option value from above form option value is:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="postformmy" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <input type="text" name="postlink" style="max-width:100%"  />
       <input type="submit" name="submitpost" value="PUBLISH POST" />
      </form>
```

the Jquery code I am using to get the option value from Ist form is:

```
 $('#page_id').change(function(){
            var hellot = $('#page_id :selected').val() ;

    });
```

Now How can I put this hellot in the second form action dynamically. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   $('#page_id').change(function(){

            var hellot = $(this).find('option:selected').val() ;
            $("form[name='postformmy']").attr('action' , hellot );
    });
```

submit the form

```
$('#page_id').change(function(){

            var hellot = $(this).find('option:selected').val() ;
            $("form[name='postformmy']").attr('action' , hellot ).submit();
    });
```

Comment: I have not used your first line i dont know why this was not working! So I used this {var hellot = $('#page_id :selected').val();} then its working!!

Comment: can you please give me the code you gave me for submit this form I need it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do,

```
$('#page_id').change(function() {
    var hellot = $(this).val();
    $("form[name='postformmy']").attr('action' , hellot );
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. And yup FYI you really dont need to call `$(this).find('option:selected').val() ;`.